# Windows 2008 R2 VPN internal ip class

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, vpn, pptp

I've managed to setup a Windows 2008 R2 as a VPN (PPTP) server via the Network Policy and Access Services, the server has one network interface with a public IP address (80.9x.xxx.xx) and I am able to connect remotely and access my internal network.

I've setup the VPN service to use a predefined IP pool from which can assign an IP to a client, class 10.0.5.0/24.

Using tcpdump on a internal Linux server (internal ip 172.23.x.x) I've determined that the ip address that the internal server sees when I ping it from the vpn client is the public ip address of the vpn server not the ip which was given to the VPN client.

```
01:12:56.322360 IP 80.9x.xxx.xx > 172.23.x.x: ICMP echo request, id 256, seq 1, length 64
01:12:56.322467 IP 172.23.xxx.x > 80.9x.xxx.xx: ICMP echo reply, id 256, seq 1, length 64
```

So my question, is how to configure the VPN server to route/forward the vpn ip class so that the internal servers see the vpn client ip address and not the server's public ip address?

Comment: You know that PPTP is horrendously insecure, right?

Comment: Yes, but for the moment I am willing to accept the risk.

Comment: ...so says everyone that has implemented PPTP (just for now). Honestly, it's not that difficult to set up a proper, modern, secure VPN.

Comment: Ok, I just installed a Centos + OpenVpn and I have the same problem. What am I missing?